# in identity server 4 use a token received from a react client and use it to authorize in the c# controllers

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core-webapi, identityserver4

I have a react application that calls identity server 4 and receives an access token.   I am then putting this access token as a bearer token to c# api calls.   The c# api calls are always unauthorized.  I don't know how to have to 2  Identity Server 4 clients be able to authenticate the same token.

here is my identity server config

```
 using IdentityModel;
    using IdentityServer4;
    using IdentityServer4.Models;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    
    namespace IdentityServer
    {
        public class Config
        {
            public static IEnumerable<Client> Clients =>
                new Client[]
                {
                    new Client
                    {
                        ClientId = "react_client",
                        ClientName = "React Client",
                        AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Code,
                        RequireClientSecret = false,
                        RedirectUris = { "http://localhost:3000/registration/callback" },
                        PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "http://localhost:3000/registration/" },
                        AllowedCorsOrigins = { "https://localhost:3001" },
                        AllowedScopes =
                        {
                            IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                            IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
                            "api"
                        },
                        AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = true,
                        RequirePkce = true
                    },
                    new Client
                    {
                        ClientId = "api",
                        AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ClientCredentials,
                        ClientSecrets = { new Secret("api_secret".Sha256()) },
                        AllowedScopes = { "api" }
                    }
                };
    
            public static IEnumerable<ApiScope> ApiScopes =>
                new ApiScope[]
                {
                    new ApiScope("api", "API")
                };
    
            public static IEnumerable<ApiResource> ApiResources =>
                new ApiResource[]
                {
                    new ApiResource("api", "My API")
                    {
                        Scopes = { "api" }
                    }
                };
    
            public static IEnumerable<IdentityResource> IdentityResources =>
                new IdentityResource[]
                {
                    new IdentityResources.OpenId(),
                    new IdentityResources.Profile(),
                    new IdentityResources.Email()
                };
        }
    }
```

in my program.cs of the c# backend for my react application I turned most things off for authentication.

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication("Bearer")
    .AddJwtBearer("Bearer", options =>
  

      {
            options.Authority = "https://localhost:7014";
            options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateAudience = false,
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = false, // Disable signing key validation
                ValidateIssuer = false, // Optionally, disable issuer validation for testing
                ValidateLifetime = false // Still validate the token's lifetime
            };
        });
```

In my react application I am successfully being sent to Identity Server 4 and I Log In. I receive a token and that token is sent as a bearer token to c# controllers but the c# controller can never  pass authentication.

here is a controller

```
  [Authorize]
      [HttpGet]
      public async Task<ActionResult<UserDTO>> GetCurrentUser()
      {
          // Find user by email claim
          var email = User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Email);
          var user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(email);

          if (user == null)
          {
              return NotFound("User not found");
          }

          UserDTO userDTO = new UserDTO
          {
              Mail = user.Email,
              UserName = user.UserName,
              DisplayName = User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Name)
          };

          return Ok(userDTO);
      }
  }
```

here is one of the tokens if you put it in the https://jwt.io/ token reader it looks ok

> eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjMzQjZGRUEyRjQ4QUMxRURERTY2OTdGRkVDREQ1NUMzIiwidHlwIjoiYXQrand0In0.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.mpV-UYXFUrOVg91MwgBtbnF8I3p0GSFP9L1MSeeEkFWMUcXgpq88a9xrcH4DtDpiOUh9nv78bjb9ocaFvUD_DMS2ZStMcB2vVNBos72gDqMMChaobnlkNOLHDU1nG7B7Nh4FoJzDo3Isl0IxlUTeXmUC0OksbpbSyj66fZUx5y61RR8Vr6dicsXaq7E6VeN2e8zdT-_ssvozxe9R-jRkarjLarxo2KB3tRb-ysAP3jA5wDvG9rKqvv1acRIeKs9dprvUN2-3JvzRXpj2uobpBPkFqdokHf4joWiTlN-dP9S_NYzsBzgSM4w2orr83REb6KWNTkZKWx3o6nMoSiozzQ

Comment: In general, you should use HTTPS everywhere, as cookies are getting blocked over HTTP, and this is a common problem when doing openid connect (IdentityServer). also, add the code you use to get the token (AddOpenIDConnect..) , I have blogged about many of the issues here: https://nestenius.se/

Comment: Add ALLOWED_ORIGINS url for your react client url 
register with UseCors in applicationBuilder